# How to produce a 3D surface plot by rotating the 2D plot of a function?

Tags: pgfplots, rotating, 3d

What I want to do is to produce a 3d plot of a surface of revolution. So far I have achieved the following code...

```
\documentclass[border= 5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{colormap={bluered}{rgb255(0cm)=(0,0,180);rgb255(1cm)=(0,255,255);rgb255(2cm)=(100,255,0);rgb255(3cm)=(255,255,0);rgb255(4cm)=(255,0,0); rgb255(5cm)=(128,0,0)}} 
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture} 
\begin{axis} [colormap/bluered]
\addplot3 [surf,samples=100,domain=0:180,y domain=0:2*pi]({x},{sin(x)*cos(deg(y))},{sin(x)*sin(deg(y))}); 
\end{axis} 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

This ends up in the function on sin(x) along the x axis, and rotated around the x axis again forming a lobe...The image is here:

[image]

What I need is... the function (let's say sin(x)), to be along the x axis but rotated around the z axis...(The image should be like the waves on the water when a rock falls in...for the sin(x)).

Also there is a problem with the colours...It seems that those yellows on top shouldn't be there...

Answer (score 5):

For plots like this, it's typically a good idea to use `z buffer=sort` to make sure the elements appear in the right order.

To get a surface made up of a function rotated around the z axis, you can use an expression like:

```
    ({sin(x)*y},{cos(x)*y},{ <function of y> });
```

where `function of y` is the function you want to rotate:

[image]

```
\documentclass[border= 5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture} 
\begin{axis} [colormap/greenyellow, axis equal]
\addplot3 [surf,shader=faceted interp, samples=25,domain=0:360,y domain=0:1080, z buffer=sort]
    ({sin(x)*y},{cos(x)*y},{cos(y)*50}); 
\end{axis} 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: That's exactly what I mean... But when trying to compile it I get the following... "./bbb.tex:8: Dimension too large. <recently read> \pgf@xa l.8 \end{axis}  ?"  bbb is the name of the file....

Comment: @Ariscampis: Does that happen when you try to compile my example, or have you changed something in the code?

Comment: Nothing changed...I copied your code and I pasted it...

Comment: @Ariscampis: What version of PGFPlots are you using? And how are you compiling the document (`pdflatex`? `lualatex`?)

Comment: I use TexShop 2.47 (where can I find the PGFPlots version?) and I compiled the code with both pdflatex and lualatex...I get the same message with both...

Comment: @Ariscampis: The version number is printed in the `.log` file.

Comment: Found it!! Package: pgfplots 2011/12/29 v1.5.1 (git show 1.5.1-4-g53e640f )

Comment: @Ariscampis: Hm, that's not too outdated, but maybe you could try updating the package to the current version (`1.8`)?

Comment: Update successfull! Works like a charm now!!!! Thanks Jake!!!

Comment: @Jake: Why do you set "y domain" to be 0:1080? Why are three revolutions necessary?

Comment: The `y domain` refers to the radius in this case: The plot shows three full wavelengths (three troughs, three peaks)